# How do I pass command line args in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a py file that takes a file name as a command line argument like so:

```
file_name = str(sys.argv[1])
file = open(file_name)
result = main_loop(file)
print(result)
```

I want to be able to test this py file with pytest

Test Code:

```
import py_loop
import pytest


    def test_loop():
        
        file = open('test_data.json')
        assert py_loop.main_loop(file) == 'Result'
```

The above errors. How can I test the program with command line args?

Comment: Refactor so that code is behind `if __name__ == "__main__":`, then you can call `main_loop` _without_ running the rest (which was presumably the point of extracting that function to start with).

Comment: Are you trying to tests with test data say in `test_data` folder?

Comment: Also, it would help to see the entirely of `py_loop.main_loop`

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure your code appears exactly as you have it. What you show would cause syntax errors. Also, [please don't make us guess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) about error messages - copy and paste, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and format as code.

Answer (score 2):

The pytest framework has a specific way of passing command-line arguments. You can do this via a `conftest.py` file or via a pytest plugin. Here's how to do this via a `conftest.py` file:

```py
# /home/user/conftest.py
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--stringvalue', action='store', dest='stringvalue')
```

```py
# /home/user/test_first.py
def test_test1(request):
    assert 'checkme' == request.config.getoption('stringvalue')
```

```sh
$ pytest /home/user/test_first.py --stringvalue checkme
```

The example above shows you how to set a `conftest.py` file, how to use that in a test, and how you would set the arg when you run `pytest` via the command-line.